# How to reorder items in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table (call it `my_table`) that can be simplified like this: NAME, SEQ_NO, LOCKED.

Items get removed and added and I want to reorder them (modify SEQ_NO) in a way that the sequence always goes from 1 to COUNT(*) and items that are locked retain their SEQ_NO and no unlocked item would get that number. Only unlocked items are updated with new SEQ_NO.

Example:

This

```
NAME  SEQ_NO    LOCKED
Foo   1         N
Bar   3         Y
Abc   4         Y
Baz   5         N
Cde   7         N
```

would result in:

```
NAME  SEQ_NO    LOCKED
Foo   1         N
Baz   2         N
Bar   3         Y
Abc   4         Y
Cde   5         N
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What happens if you have these 3 values: `seq_no=1 locked=Y`, `seq_no=5 locked=N`, `seq_no=10 locked=Y`?

Comment: the problem is too hard. Please add details about the problem. Contraints of the input data that may help. What you delete? how many rows? What rows you delete? what else do we know about input?

Comment: There are around 200+ items, each item also has expiration time, that gets checked periodically and all items that have expired or were deleted are deleted from this table, it's usually only a few (up to 20) rows, but there are several hundreds of thousands of types inside this table (the examples are basically displayed items of one type).

Comment: Why do people forget that tables have names?  It is such a common problem with SQL questions, and it never fails to amaze me.  Given that the answers so far have used **my_table** as the name, I'll edit that into the question so everyone who answers uses the same name.

Comment: 1. I don't understand. It has 200 items or 200k items? 2. How other way are items related? They have only seq_no(which is incremental), lock flag(these two say something about relation between items) name, expiration time(these does not say anything about their relation)

Comment: dare I ask why?  why the need to maintain this seq_no in the data itself?  What do you need seq_no for exactly?  For example, if needed for ranking some output, you can do that on the fly via analytic functions.  More input on your use of seq_no & locked concepts would probably lead to a better solution for u

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are times when your goals of `1..COUNT(*)` numbering and 'do not renumber locked rows' lead to irresolvable conflict.  For example:

```
NAME  SEQ_NO    LOCKED
Foo    1        N
Bar   13        Y
Abc   14        Y
Baz    5        N
Cde    7        N
```

I will assume that the required output for this scenario is:

```
NAME  SEQ_NO    LOCKED
Foo    1        N
Baz    2        N
Cde    3        N
Bar   13        Y
Abc   14        Y
```

You example shows the unlocked data being kept in its original sequence number order, and the locked data obviously doesn't get a new number.

I assume that there are no duplicate sequence numbers in the original data.

---

#### Quick Summary

It is an interesting and tricky problem.  The key to reordering the data is knowing where to place the unlocked rows.  In the example data:

```
NAME  OLD_SEQ   LOCKED   NEW_SEQ
Foo   1         N        1
Bar   3         Y        3
Abc   4         Y        4
Baz   5         N        2
Cde   7         N        5
```

We can give the unlocked rows a sequence number counting from 1..3, so we end up with pairs of *ord:old* sequence **A { 1:1, 2:5, 3:7 }**.  We can generate a list of slots for the result set 1..5.  We remove from that list of slots those slots held by locked rows, leaving { 1, 2, 5 } as the list of slots to be occupied by unlocked rows in the reordered list.  We then number those in order too, leaving pairs *ord:new* **B { 1:1, 2:2, 3:5 }**.  We can then join these two lists, A and B, on the first field and project away the sequencing, to leave pairs of *new:old* slot numbers **C { 1:1, 2:5, 5:7 }**.  The locked rows produce a set of *new:old* values where *new = old* in each case, so **D { 3:3, 4:4 }**.  The final result is the union of C and D, so the result set contains:

- old sequence number 1 in new sequence number 1;
- old 5 in new 2;
- (old 3 in new 3);
- (old 4 in new 4); and
- old 7 in new 5.

This works for the case where the locked rows have sequence number 13 and 14 too; the unlocked rows are allocated new sequence numbers 1, 2, 3 and the locked rows remain unchanged.  One of the comments to the question asks about '1 locked, 5 unlocked, 10 locked'; this would produce '1 locked, 2 unlocked, 10 locked'.

Getting to do that in SQL takes quite a lot of SQL.  Someone with a good command of the OLAP functionality might be able to get there quicker than my code does.  And converting the SELECT results into an UPDATE statement is tricky too (and not fully solved by me).  But being able to get the data presented in the correct result order is crucial, and the key to solving that is the ordering steps represented by lists A and B.

---

### TDQD — Test Driven Query Design

As with any complex SQL query operation, the secret is to build the query up step by step.  As noted, we need to treat locked and unlocked rows differently.  In this case, the target is ultimately an UPDATE statement, but we need to know how to generate the data for the UPDATE, so we do the SELECT first.

#### Renumberable rows

```
-- Query 1
SELECT Name, Seq_No
  FROM My_Table
 WHERE Locked = 'N'
 ORDER BY Seq_No;

NAME  SEQ_NO
Foo   1
Baz   5
Cde   7
```

When appropriate, these can be ordered with an ORDER BY clause, but sub-queries typically don't allow ORDER BY clauses and we need to generate a number.  With OLAP functions, you can probably do this more compactly.  In Oracle, you may be able to use ROWNUM to generate row numbers.  There's a trick that will work in any DBMS, though it is not particularly fast.

#### Renumbered rows assuming no interference from locked rows

```
-- Query 2
SELECT m1.Name, m1.Seq_No AS Old_Seq, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
  FROM My_Table m1
  JOIN My_Table m2
    ON m1.Seq_No >= m2.Seq_No
 WHERE m1.Locked = 'N' AND m2.Locked = 'N'
 GROUP BY m1.Name, m1.Seq_No
 ORDER BY New_Seq;

NAME  Old_Seq   New_Seq
Foo   1         1
Baz   5         2
Cde   7         3
```

This is a non-equijoin and that is what makes this a not particularly fast operation.

#### Unrenumberable rows

```
-- Query 3
SELECT Name, Seq_No
  FROM My_Table
 WHERE Locked = 'Y'
 ORDER BY Seq_No;

NAME  Seq_No
Bar   3
Abc   4
```

#### New sequence numbers

Suppose we manage to get a list of numbers, 1..N (where N = 5 in the sample data).  We remove from that list the locked entries (3, 4) leaving (1, 2, 5).  When those are ranked (1 = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 5), we can join the ranking with the unlocked records new sequence, but use the other number as the final sequence number of the record.  That just leaves us with a few little problems to resolve.  First, generating each of the numbers 1..N; we can do one of those ghastly little non-equijoin tricks, but there should be a better way:

```
-- Query 4
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Ordinal
  FROM My_Table AS t1
  JOIN My_Table AS t2
    ON t1.Seq_No >= t2.Seq_No
 GROUP BY t1.Seq_No
 ORDER BY Ordinal;

Ordinal
1
2
3
4
5
```

We can then remove the locked sequence numbers from this list:

```
-- Query 5
SELECT Ordinal
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ordinal
          FROM My_Table t1
          JOIN My_Table t2
            ON t1.Seq_No <= t2.Seq_No
         GROUP BY t1.Seq_No
       ) O
 WHERE O.Ordinal NOT IN (SELECT Seq_No FROM My_Table WHERE Locked = 'Y')
 ORDER BY Ordinal;

 Ordinal
 1
 2
 5
```

Now we need to rank those, which means another of the self-joins, but this time on that expression.  Time to use 'Common Table Expressions' or CTE, also known as a 'WITH clause':

```
-- Query 6
WITH HoleyList AS
    (SELECT ordinal
       FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) ordinal
               FROM My_Table t1
               JOIN My_Table t2
                 ON t1.seq_no <= t2.seq_no
              GROUP BY t1.seq_no
            ) O
      WHERE O.Ordinal NOT IN (SELECT Seq_No FROM My_Table WHERE Locked = 'Y')
    )
SELECT H1.Ordinal, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
  FROM HoleyList H1
  JOIN HoleyList H2
    ON H1.Ordinal >= H2.Ordinal
 GROUP BY H1.Ordinal
 ORDER BY New_Seq;

Ordinal  New_Seq
1        1
2        2
5        3
```

#### Finishing up

So, now we need to join that result with Query 2 to get the final numbers for the unlocked rows, and then the union of that with Query 3 to get the required output.  Of course, we have to get the correct values for Locked in the output too.  Still going step-wise:

```
-- Query 7
WITH
Query2 AS
   (SELECT m1.Name, m1.Seq_No AS Old_Seq, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
      FROM My_Table m1
      JOIN My_Table m2 ON m1.Seq_No <= m2.Seq_No
     WHERE m1.Locked = 'N' AND m2.Locked = 'N'
     GROUP BY m1.Name, m1.Seq_No
   ),
HoleyList AS
   (SELECT ordinal
      FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ordinal
              FROM My_Table t1
              JOIN My_Table t2
                ON t1.seq_no <= t2.seq_no
             GROUP BY t1.seq_no
           ) O
      WHERE O.Ordinal NOT IN (SELECT Seq_No FROM My_Table WHERE Locked = 'Y')
    ),
Reranking AS    
   (SELECT H1.Ordinal, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
      FROM HoleyList H1
      JOIN HoleyList H2
        ON H1.Ordinal >= H2.Ordinal
     GROUP BY H1.Ordinal
   )
SELECT r.Ordinal, r.New_Seq, q.Name, q.Old_Seq, 'N' Locked
  FROM Reranking r
  JOIN Query2    q
    ON r.New_Seq = q.New_Seq
 ORDER BY r.New_Seq;

Ordinal  New_Seq  Name  Old_Seq  Locked
1        1        Cde   7        N
2        2        Baz   5        N
5        3        Foo   1        N
```

This needs to be combined with a variant of Query 3:

```
-- Query 3a
SELECT Seq_No Ordinal, Seq_No New_Seq, Name, Seq_No Old_Seq, Locked
  FROM My_Table
 WHERE Locked = 'Y'
 ORDER BY New_Seq;

Ordinal  New_Seq  Name  Old_Seq  Locked
3        3        Bar   3        Y
4        4        Abc   4        Y
```

#### The result set

Combining these yields:

```
-- Query 8
WITH
Query2 AS
   (SELECT m1.Name, m1.Seq_No AS Old_Seq, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
      FROM My_Table m1
      JOIN My_Table m2 ON m1.Seq_No <= m2.Seq_No
     WHERE m1.Locked = 'N' AND m2.Locked = 'N'
     GROUP BY m1.Name, m1.Seq_No
   ),
HoleyList AS
   (SELECT ordinal
      FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ordinal
              FROM My_Table t1
              JOIN My_Table t2
                ON t1.seq_no <= t2.seq_no
             GROUP BY t1.seq_no
           ) O
      WHERE O.Ordinal NOT IN (SELECT Seq_No FROM My_Table WHERE Locked = 'Y')
    ),
Reranking AS    
   (SELECT H1.Ordinal, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
      FROM HoleyList H1
      JOIN HoleyList H2
        ON H1.Ordinal >= H2.Ordinal
     GROUP BY H1.Ordinal
   ),
Query7 AS
   (SELECT r.Ordinal, r.New_Seq, q.Name, q.Old_Seq, 'N' Locked
      FROM Reranking r
      JOIN Query2    q
        ON r.New_Seq = q.New_Seq
   ),
Query3a AS
   (SELECT Seq_No Ordinal, Seq_No New_Seq, Name, Seq_No Old_Seq, Locked
      FROM My_Table
     WHERE Locked = 'Y'
   )
SELECT Ordinal, New_Seq, Name, Old_Seq, Locked
  FROM Query7
UNION
SELECT Ordinal, New_Seq, Name, Old_Seq, Locked
  FROM Query3a
 ORDER BY New_Seq;
```

This gives the result:

```
Ordinal  New_Seq  Name  Old_Seq  Locked
1        1        Cde   7        N
2        2        Baz   5        N
3        3        Bar   3        Y
4        4        Abc   4        Y
5        3        Foo   1        N
```

So, it is possible (though far from easy) to write a SELECT statement that orders the data correctly.

#### Converting into an UPDATE operation

Now we have to find a way to get that monstrosity into an UPDATE statement.  Left to my own devices, I'd think in terms of a transaction that selects the result of Query 8 into a temporary table, then deletes all the records from the source table (`My_Table`) and inserts the appropriate project of the result of Query 8 into the original table and then commits.

Oracle doesn't seem to support dynamically created 'per session' temporary tables; only global temporary tables.  And there are sound reasons not to use those, for all they are SQL Standard.  Nevertheless, it will do the trick here where I'm not sure what else will work:

Separately from this work:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ReSequenceTable
(
    Name     CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Seq_No   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Locked   CHAR(1) NOT NULL
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Then:

```
-- Query 8a
BEGIN;   -- May be unnecessary and/or unsupported in Oracle
INSERT INTO ReSequenceTable(Name, Seq_No, Locked)
    WITH
    Query2 AS
       (SELECT m1.Name, m1.Seq_No AS Old_Seq, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
          FROM My_Table m1
          JOIN My_Table m2 ON m1.Seq_No <= m2.Seq_No
         WHERE m1.Locked = 'N' AND m2.Locked = 'N'
         GROUP BY m1.Name, m1.Seq_No
       ),
    HoleyList AS
       (SELECT ordinal
          FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ordinal
                  FROM My_Table t1
                  JOIN My_Table t2
                    ON t1.seq_no <= t2.seq_no
                 GROUP BY t1.seq_no
               ) O
          WHERE O.Ordinal NOT IN (SELECT Seq_No FROM My_Table WHERE Locked = 'Y')
        ),
    Reranking AS    
       (SELECT H1.Ordinal, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
          FROM HoleyList H1
          JOIN HoleyList H2
            ON H1.Ordinal >= H2.Ordinal
         GROUP BY H1.Ordinal
       ),
    Query7 AS
       (SELECT r.Ordinal, r.New_Seq, q.Name, q.Old_Seq, 'N' Locked
          FROM Reranking r
          JOIN Query2    q
            ON r.New_Seq = q.New_Seq
       ),
    Query3a AS
       (SELECT Seq_No Ordinal, Seq_No New_Seq, Name, Seq_No Old_Seq, Locked
          FROM My_Table
         WHERE Locked = 'Y'
       )
    SELECT Name, Ordinal, Locked
      FROM Query7
    UNION
    SELECT Name, Ordinal, Locked
      FROM Query3a;

DELETE FROM My_Table;
INSERT INTO My_Table(Name, Seq_No, Locked) FROM ReSequenceTable;
COMMIT;
```

You probably can do it with an appropriate UPDATE; you need to do some of the thinking.

---

### Summary

It isn't easy, but it can be done.

The *key step* (at least for me) was the result set from *Query 6*, which worked out the new positions of the unlocked rows in the updated result set.  That is not immediately obvious, but it is crucial to producing the answer.

The rest is simply support code wrapped around that key step.

As noted previously, there are likely to be many ways to improve some of the queries.  For example, generating the sequence `1..N` from the table might be as simple as `SELECT ROWNUM FROM My_Table`, which compacts the query (highly beneficial — it is verbose).  There are OLAP functions; one or more of those may be able to help with the ranking operations (probably more concisely; like performing better too).

So, this is not a polished final answer; but it is a strong push in the right general direction.

---

#### PoC Testing

The code has been tested against Informix.  I had to use somewhat different notations because Informix does not (yet) support CTEs.  It does have very convenient, very simple, per session dynamic temporary tables introduced by `INTO TEMP <temp-table-name>` which appears where the ORDER BY clause might otherwise appear.  Thus, I simulated Query 8a with:

```
+ BEGIN;
+ SELECT O.Ordinal
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ordinal
          FROM My_Table AS t1
          JOIN My_Table AS t2
            ON t1.Seq_No <= t2.Seq_No
         GROUP BY t1.Seq_No
       ) AS O
 WHERE O.Ordinal NOT IN (SELECT Seq_No FROM My_Table WHERE Locked = 'Y')
 INTO TEMP HoleyList;
+ SELECT * FROM HoleyList ORDER BY Ordinal;
1
2
5
+ SELECT H1.Ordinal, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
  FROM HoleyList AS H1
  JOIN HoleyList AS H2
    ON H1.Ordinal >= H2.Ordinal
 GROUP BY H1.Ordinal
 INTO TEMP ReRanking;
+ SELECT * FROM ReRanking ORDER BY Ordinal;
1|1
2|2
5|3
+ SELECT m1.Name, m1.Seq_No AS Old_Seq, COUNT(*) AS New_Seq
  FROM My_Table m1
  JOIN My_Table m2
    ON m1.Seq_No >= m2.Seq_No
 WHERE m1.Locked = 'N' AND m2.Locked = 'N'
 GROUP BY m1.Name, m1.Seq_No
  INTO TEMP Query2;
+ SELECT * FROM Query2 ORDER BY New_Seq;
Foo|1|1
Baz|5|2
Cde|7|3
+ SELECT r.Ordinal, r.New_Seq, q.Name, q.Old_Seq, 'N' Locked
  FROM Reranking r
  JOIN Query2    q
    ON r.New_Seq = q.New_Seq
  INTO TEMP Query7;
+ SELECT * FROM Query7 ORDER BY Ordinal;
1|1|Foo|1|N
2|2|Baz|5|N
5|3|Cde|7|N
+ SELECT Seq_NO Ordinal, Seq_No New_Seq, Name, Seq_No Old_Seq, Locked
  FROM My_Table
 WHERE Locked = 'Y'
  INTO TEMP Query3a;
+ SELECT * FROM Query3a ORDER BY Ordinal;
3|3|Bar|3|Y
4|4|Abc|4|Y
+ SELECT Ordinal, New_Seq, Name, Old_Seq, Locked
  FROM Query7
UNION
SELECT Ordinal, New_Seq, Name, Old_Seq, Locked
  FROM Query3a
  INTO TEMP Query8;
+ SELECT * FROM Query8 ORDER BY Ordinal;
1|1|Foo|1|N
2|2|Baz|5|N
3|3|Bar|3|Y
4|4|Abc|4|Y
5|3|Cde|7|N
+ ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Long Answer. You can compete to TLAS(The Longest Answer on StackOverflow) :) I'll read it in my coffe breaks ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
merge into my_table
using (
   select rowid as rid,
          row_number() over (order by seq_no) as rn
   from my_table
   where locked = 'N'
) t on (t.rid = my_table.rowid) 
when matched then update
   set seq_no = t.rn;
```

Comment: I like this merge worked great after parens around t.rid = my_table.rowid

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think it only works when the locked record should be the last in the final result. for example if you add another row with `seq_no = 4, locked='N'` and you'll get 2 records with `seq_no=3`

Comment: Good point. The question from @kane77 is not clear on that. I assumed the statement "*items that are locked retain their SEQ_NO*" means that they should never be touched and should not be considered during re-numbering. If they should be considered and re-numbered this can probably by sorting them "at the end" inside the over clause.

Comment: Ok, this was not very clear. The locked items should retain their number, this means that this seq_no should not be assigned to any other item. (Basically this means their position is locked and if any item that has lower seq_no is removed when renumbering other non-locked items would be moved before them.

Comment: @kane77: then my statement should do what you want.

Comment: not quite, I meant that if item is locked on seq_no 3 then no other unlocked element should have this seq_no, if there are free seq_no before the item then the unlocked items should be moved before, else just place it after.

Comment: @kane77: then my solution will not do what you want, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This might not get all your data cases, but it works for the example data:

```
update my_table mt
set seq_no = 
(with renumber as (select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ rownum rn, name, seq_no, locked
from
(
select * from my_table
where locked = 'N'
order by seq_no
)
)
select rn from renumber rn where rn.seq_no = mt.seq_no
)
where locked = 'N'
;
```

Fully worked out example below:

```
create table my_table as
select 'Foo' name, 1 seq_no, 'N' locked from dual union
select 'Bar' name, 3 seq_no, 'Y' locked from dual union
select 'Baz' name, 5 seq_no, 'N' locked from dual 
order by seq_no
;

select * from my_table
order by seq_no
;


update my_table mt
set seq_no = 
(with renumber as (select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ rownum rn, name, seq_no, locked
from
(
select * from my_table
where locked = 'N'
order by seq_no
)
)
select rn from renumber rn where rn.seq_no = mt.seq_no
)
where locked = 'N'
;

select * from my_table
order by seq_no
;
```

Comment: this would only work when the Locked items are last.. however as I clarified later I meant that if item is locked on seq_no 3 then no other unlocked element should have this seq_no, if there are free seq_no before the item then the unlocked items should be moved before, else just place it after. I'm not sure if it is possible to do in one update statement..

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
  yourTable_unlocked_resequenced
AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    CASE WHEN
      yourTable.locked ='N'
    THEN
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY locked ORDER BY seq_no)
    END AS unlocked_seq_no
  FROM
    yourTable
)
,
  master_list
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY seq_no)       AS seq_no
  FROM
    yourTable
)
,
  master_list_unlocked_resequenced
AS
(
  SELECT
    master_list.seq_no,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yourTable.locked ORDER BY master_list.seq_no) AS unlocked_seq_no
  FROM
     master_list
  LEFT JOIN
     yourTable
       ON  yourTable.seq_no = master_list.seq_no
       AND yourTable.locked = 'Y'
  WHERE
    yourTable.locked IS NULL
)
SELECT
  original.*,
  modified.*,
  COALESCE(modified.seq_no, original_seq_no) AS final_seq_no
FROM
  yourTable_unlocked_resequenced      AS original
LEFT JOIN
  master_list_unlocked_resequenced    AS modified
    ON original.unlocked_seq_no = modified.unlocked_seq_no
```

It may be possbile to condense that, but I would say that it works.

Using your current values...

```
Seq_No           1 3 4 5 7
Locked           N Y Y N N
Unlocked_Seq_No  1     2 3

Seq_No           1 2 3 4 5
Unlocked_Seq_No  1 2     3

Original_Seq_No  1 3 4 5 7
Modified_Seq_No  1 3 4 2 5
```

If you changed your data slightly, you get the following, with one value (the `8`) sitting outside of the sequence due to it being locked...

```
Seq_No           1 3 5 7 8
Locked           N Y N N Y
Unlocked_Seq_No  1   2 3  

Seq_No           1 2 3 4 5
Unlocked_Seq_No  1 2   3 4

Original_Seq_No  1 3 5 7 8
Modified_Seq_No  1 3 2 4 8
```